# Printing a HTML page with a TSP100 printer from the command line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, printing

I am trying to print a html page from the command line using a TSP100 printer (receipt printer) on Ubuntu. I have read several pages to find a solution and I have tried so far the next solutions:

```
lp -o document-format=text/html test.html
```

The above command prints a page in plain text so that I see the HTML tags as the driver is not able to render the HTML code.

```
html2ps test.html | lp
```

I have used html2ps to create a postscript and print it but it prints an empty page although I can preview the postscript correctly. However, I have downloaded an example of postscript from a website and it works with lp. So I guess the output generated by html2ps is not compatible with the printer.

I can print an HTML page using a browser. I also tested with another printer and I got the same result.

Any help would be much appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to somehow preserve the intended HTML formatting, you could try [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/).

The following HTML file

```
<H1>Hello World!</H1>
Welcome
```

renders as

```
Hello World!
============

Welcome
```

using

```
pandoc hello.html -t plain
```